# percentage-based string comparison in php

Tags: php, string-comparison

I'm looking for a library in PHP that will allow me to compare two strings, and determine if they similar.
For example:

```
apple apple 100%
apple aple  80%
```

and so forth.
any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

> similar_text — Calculate the similarity between two strings
>
> **Description**
>
> ```
> int similar_text ( string $first , string $second [, float &$percent ] )
> ```
>
> This calculates the similarity between two strings as described in Programming Classics: Implementing the World's Best Algorithms by Oliver (ISBN 0-131-00413-1). Note that this implementation does not use a stack as in Oliver's pseudo code, but recursive calls which may or may not speed up the whole process. Note also that the complexity of this algorithm is O(N**3) where N is the length of the longest string...

Does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), [similar-text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php), [soundex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php), or [metaphone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
similar_text('apple', 'apple', $percentage);
echo $percentage. // 100

similar_text('apple', 'aple', $percentage);
echo $percentage. // 88.88
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you're doing this comparison as a part of a data extraction from a database, many DB engines have a SOUNDS LIKE (or SOUNDEX) implementation. Doing this in the DB server would be faster than doing it in PHP.